# prolog variable not exist

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Here is my simple program to test if else and function call in swi prolog. What is wrong with below code which says `rule` does not exist

```
call_rule(Roll):-
(
    member(Roll,[123]),
    writeln('inside call rule'),
    nb_getval(rule, 'this is the rule')
).
print_roll(Roll) :-
    (   Roll < 2 ->
        writeln('not a roll')
    ;
        (  Roll > 1243 ->
           writeln('not a roll'),writeln('this is 2nd alternative'),writeln('this is third alternative')
        ;
           ( Roll =:= 12 ->
                writeln('boxcars')
            ;
                ( call_rule(Roll) ->
                    nb_getval(rule, RULE),
            writeln('snake eyes')
                ;
                    nb_getval(rule,SUBJECT),
            writeln(SUBJECT)    
                )
            )
        )
    ).
```

result:

```
3 ?- print_roll(123).  
inside call rule
ERROR: nb_getval/2: variable `rule' does not exist
```

Comment: generally, you should **avoid** global variables, in any language, and much more in Prolog

Comment: I second what CappeliC wrote! **Avoid** `nb_setval/2` and all predicates like it: They cannot be used as true relations and you therefore do not benefit from the usual advantages (generality etc.) of declarative solutions.

Comment: @CapelliC: I could not understand your point. I am beginner in prolog, I learned this way of writing looking at various articles. I appreciate if you can show me optimal version of this code.

Comment: @mat: thanks for pointing, but still muddleing to get advantage of generality

Comment: @user2129623: Try to think in terms of *relations*. In this case, you apparently want to define a relation between a roll and its name, so think about (for example) `roll_name/2`. Generality: You can use such a predicate *in all directions*, for example: "Which rolls and names exist?" (`?- roll_name(R, N).`) or "Which rolls correspond to a given name?". `nb_setval/2` and other predicates like it usually impose *a single direction*: You may be able to determine a name for a given roll, but not vice versa. Also, you cannot use your predicates in isolation any more, as you have already seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can get a value from the non-backtrackable store, you need to `nb_setval` the key:

**Example**:

```
?- nb_getval(a,X).
ERROR: nb_getval/2: variable `a' does not exist
?- nb_setval(a,foo).
true.

?- nb_getval(a,X).
X = foo.
```

Comment: thanks a lot, so `nb_setval` and `nb_getval` are inbuild methods??

Comment: They are part of a library my PhD supervisor wrote once. But they are asumed to be builtin commands in most Prolog implementations (swipl, hProlog,...) In some dialects, they have different names. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.prolog/sNBaaewYbqE) for a list.

Comment: `nb_linkval` and `nb_setval` are these both same? gives same result

Comment: Not entirely: `nb_setval` **copies** the value whereas `nb_linkval` associates the value. If after setting the store, you instantiate the value further, this can have effects on `nb_linkval`. Although, as documented, only experts better use `nb_linkval` since the semantics of links and backtracking are poorly defined. One better pays a bit of performance for more convenience.

Comment: @user2129623: I did not downvote... (did +1), don't know why someone downvoted... And it definitely makes some sense since Prolog normally tends to be as much directional as possible *get/set* are not the way Prolog normally handles data...